# Check RenderSectionAsync in _Layout is empty or not (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@await RenderSectionAsync("SpecialHeader", required: false)
```

Some views have this and some don't:

```
@section SpecialHeader
{
    // something
}
```

So far so good.

Now how can I check whether `RenderSectionAsync` (in `_Layout.cshtml`) is null (empty) or not?

I want something like this:

```
if (RenderSectionAsync == null)   // this is in my mind
{
    // Public Header
}
else
{
    @await RenderSectionAsync("SpecialHeader", required: false)
}
```